# How to make Google oAuth remember user approval for permissions?

Tags: oauth, facebook

While using Google OpenID, there is an already selected option for "remember approval". How can the same be achieved for a login with OAuth 2.0 ?

It seems to ask permission everytime for the defined scope settings, whereas in facebook Oauth 2.0, it asks only once.

OpenID example from Stack Exchange, with "remember this approval" option

[image: stack exchange auth]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/10/upcoming-changes-to-oauth-20-endpoint.html

see Change #3: Server-side auto-approval

Comment: Thanks, that is what was missing in the current implementation.

Comment: I had similar problem, for now i implemented oauth2 for client side web applications http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html#CS. Downside of course is that auth token is short lived.

Comment: I did the same, client side implementation seemed faster too.